# JS: Add style onload, then remove style onclick with Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, onload

I'm very new and inexperienced with JavaScript so please excuse what may be a stupid question!

I'm trying to add a orange shadow to a drop-down selection (shipping options) in a Magento PayPal express review page with the following script to highlight that the customer needs to make a shipping option selection:

```
window.onload = function() {
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/paypal/express/review/')!= -1) {
document.querySelectorAll('select#shipping_method')[0].style.boxShadow = '0 0 4px 2px #e15500'; 
}
};
```

I then want to remove that shadow once the drop-down has been clicked to indicate to the customer that they have made the right move :-)
Some thing like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('select#shipping_method').onclick = function()  { 
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/paypal/express/review/')!= -1) 
{this.style.boxShadow = 'none'; }
};
```

Question is, how do I combine these two functions so that it works? (add shadow onload, then remove shadow onclick) I have been able to make the shadow appear onload, but cannot get both functions to work together through my lack of Javascript knowledge to date! Any ideas would be appreciated - please note I cannot edit the source HTML, and want to ensure this only runs on this specific page.

Comment: Which JS/ES version?

Comment: One issue is that you are using `querySelectorAll()`, which returns a `NodeList` and not an actual node. You could use `querySelector()` in both functions instead, but you would then need to remove the `[0]` from your first function. You can't use `.onclick` of a `NodeList`, it has to be a single `Node`.

Comment: You're also not waiting for the `window.onload` event in the second function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/paypal/express/review/')!= -1) {
  const select = document.querySelector('#shipping_method');

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    select.style.boxShadow = '0 0 4px 2px #e15500'; 
  })

  select.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.boxShadow = 'none';
  })
}
```

1. You only do this code if the url match, so you don't have to validate this twice
2. Define the dropdown so you can reuse the selector
3. Use `addEventListener` is better

Let mw know if it works for you.

Good luck.

Comment: Ohhh and one more thing, you might want to add the shadow with css (not on window load and then remove it on the click, is less code and better performance.

Comment: Glad to help! :)